# UWP XAML VisualState does not have an accessible setter

Tags: xaml, win-universal-app, visualstatemanager, visualstategroup

I have some `Button` in my `MainPage` as shown below:

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="10"  >
            <Image Stretch="None" Source="Images/GameMainMenuIcon.png" Margin="0 0 0 50" />
            <Button Style="{StaticResource ButtonGameLarge}">Button1</Button>
            <Button Style="{StaticResource ButtonGameLarge}">Button2</Button>
            <Button Style="{StaticResource ButtonGameLarge}">Button3</Button>
        </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

And in my `Style.xaml` file I wrote these styles for the `Buttons`:

```
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="ButtonGameLarge">
    <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
        <Setter.Value>
            <VisualStateGroup>

                <VisualState>
                    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                        <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="720" />
                    </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="Height" Value="80" />
                        <Setter Property="Width" Value="400" />
                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0 0 0 20" />
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>

                <VisualState>
                    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                        <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="400" />
                    </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="Height" Value="40" />
                        <Setter Property="Width" Value="200" />
                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0 0 0 10" />
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>

            </VisualStateGroup>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>

</Style>
```

But it gives me these errors:

- The property "VisualStateGroups" does not have an accessible setter.
- Cannot assign 'VisualStateGroup' into property 'VisualStateGroups', type must be assignable to 'IList'
- The property "VisualStateGroups" is not a DependencyProperty. To be used in markup, non-attached properties must be exposed on the target type with an accessible instance property "VisualStateGroups". For attached properties, the declaring type must provide static "GetVisualStateGroups"  and "SetVisualStateGroups" methods.

How can I set multiple `VisualState` for a group of elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The attached property `VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups` can be only applied to types that are derived from `FrameworkElement`.

For your problem, you can modify the style like this:

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonGameLarge" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Grid x:Name="RootGrid" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseMediumLowBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseHighBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundBaseMediumLowBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightTransparentBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseHighBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <PointerDownThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundBaseLowBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseMediumLowBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledTransparentBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualState>
                                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="720" />
                                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="RootGrid.Height" Value="80" />
                                    <Setter Target="RootGrid.Width" Value="400" />
                                    <Setter Target="RootGrid.Margin" Value="0,0,0,20" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>

                            <VisualState>
                                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="400" />
                                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="RootGrid.Height" Value="40" />
                                    <Setter Target="RootGrid.Width" Value="200" />
                                    <Setter Target="RootGrid.Margin" Value="0,0,0,10" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

As it in my code, we can attach your `VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups` to the `RootGrid` inside of `Button` which derived from `FrameworkElement`.

Answer (score 0):

You should set visual states in the control template, and than reuse the control multiple times. Here you can find [examples](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.visualstate.aspx)